# django: FileField model - 404

Tags: django

This is my first Django project and I have one problem. file1 is saved to media folder\files however when I try to download the file I'm getting 404. Any help is appreciated!

127.0.0.1:8000/about/files/2021/01/22/pyqt_tutorial_EB2ZapN.pdf

models.py

```
class Links(models.Model):
    file1 = models.FileField(upload_to = 'files/%Y/%m/%d/')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
```

html

```
        {% for link in links %}
        <div class="links1">
            <h3><a href = "{{ link.file1 }}">Download Link</a></h3>
            <p>{{ link.publish_date }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

urls.py>

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', about, name = 'about')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py>

```
# Media Folder Settings
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Update: from the admin panel if I click on the link I can see it. Maybe In the {{ link.file1 }} url something need to be changed?

Comment: You should use `{{ link.file1.url }}`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` in your template should be `{{ link.file1.url }}` to properly construct the path to the file.